# R sf ggplot labeling multiple polygon that are listed within ID

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, r-sf

Lets say I want to plot and label polygons (one polygon per row in a dataframe), I can do the following:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc_3857 <- sf::st_transform(nc, 3857)
ggplot(nc_3857[1:3, ]) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = NAME))
```

[image]
Here `NAME` refers to just one list of polygon points in the `geometry` variable which works fine.

If however, my `geometry` variable represents a list of multiple polygons for each row, how would I label them. I want a generic version that can account for lists of different lengths. For example looking at this df:

```
df <- structure(list(id= structure(1:2, .Label = c("A1", "A2"
), class = "factor"), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(
    list(structure(c(0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
    2L)), structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 2L
    ))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L)), structure(c(3.3, 3.3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.3, 0.3), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3), .Dim = c(4L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 4, 4, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 2L)), structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(3.3, 3.3, 3.8, 
3.8, 3.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
"MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
    proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 0, 
ymin = 0, xmax = 4, ymax = 4), class = "bbox"), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", 
"sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

For my output I'm looping through id and plotting the list of polygons that corresponds to each `id`, so something like this (without my loop):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = df[df$id=="A1",])
```

I would like to generically label each list of polygons so for each plot I would have "Fragment 1", "Fragment 2"...etc. like in my first image depending on how many fragments (3 in the example below for id= A1).
 [image]

Seems pretty basic but can't figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do for the purpose of plotting is to use `st_cast` to split your `MULTIPOLYGON` geometries into multiple `POLYGON` geometries. By default, this will warn that you are copying attributes (here the `id`) across geometries, which is fine in this case but might cause errors depending on the attribute (don't copy a measurement like area!) Once we have one geometry per row, it becomes easy to plot in the same way with `geom_sf_label`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, PROJ 4.9.3
df <- structure(list(id = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 2L)), structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(3.3, 3.3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), .Dim = c(4L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 2L)), structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))), list(structure(c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(3.3, 3.3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 4, ymax = 4), class = "bbox"), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
df %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON", group_or_split = TRUE, warn = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = id)) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = id))
```

[image]

In your example, this looks a bit strange because the `A2` polygons are identical to the `A1` polygons, so the colours and labels are covered up. There really are 3 `A1` labels being drawn, you can see this if you add a line `filter(id == "A1")` before the `ggplot` call:

```r
df %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON", group_or_split = TRUE, warn = FALSE) %>%
  filter(id == "A1") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = id)) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = id))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, you're just missing one line `mutate(c = paste("Fragment", seq_along(id), sep=" "))` which changes `geom_sf_label(aes(label = c))` as I was looking to name each piece differently, not all the same. Would you know how to reference each label within `id` with a loop, something like: `geom_sf_label(aes(label = df[df$id==i, "c"]))`

Comment: figured it out..`geom_sf_label(data = df[df$id==i,], aes(label = c))`